# Tip Size for Paint Sprayer on Ceiling

Tags: painting, spraying

I'm going to rent a good paint sprayer to paint popcorn ceilings. The only tip size available from the rental place is a 515. I've read this isn't the best size for interior painting, but will it suffice, and is there anything I should do to compensate for the larger-than-optimal amount of paint it will put out?

Thank you

Comment: Move quickly (the gun) and wear eye protection and a respirator. If the ceiling has been painted before any respirator will do but if a home from the 70' S or prior and this is the first time being painted you need to look into asbestos and take the appropriate precautions.

Comment: The 515 will allow a lot more paint to flow. This will be your issue and you will need to back roll for sure - which is why Ed said move the gun quickly. How big is the ceiling and does it have popcorn ? If it is small area - use a roller. if it has popcorn - make it a fluffy roller.

Comment: It's popcorn and it's a large area, more 400 sq ft. Some of it's been painted before (albeit very poorly and unevenly) and some parts are unpainted.